# PMML Execution in Spark for predictions

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, pmml

I am new to pmml files. I have a pmml file (Which contains some model information). we want to process that pmml file in spark for predictions.

As a result of execution, it will give some prediction values as target fields and outfields.

how to process pmml in spark scala?

Any sample example/documentation please.

Comment: Welcome to SO; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PMML4S-Spark](https://github.com/autodeployai/pmml4s-spark) to process PMML in Spark Scala, for example:

```scala
import org.pmml4s.spark.ScoreModel

val model = ScoreModel.fromFile("the/pmml/file/path")
val scoreDf = model.transform(df)
```

The `scoreDf` is a Spark DataFrame with outfields that are decided by your pmml.